Does there exists a $\sigma \in S_{2N}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sigma(2n-1) ^ {\sigma(2n)}$ is a perfect square?
Does there exists a $\sigma \in S_{2N}$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^{N} \sigma(2n-1) ^ {\sigma(2n)}$ is a perfect square? ($S_k$ denotes the group of permutations of $\{1, 2, 3, ..., k\}$)
To me, it seems that for all values of $N$, there exist such $\sigma$. I've verified the conjecture for $N≤9$ and for $N≤8$, I even found the permutations that produces the largest squares:
$$1^2 = 1^2$$
$$3^2 = 2^3+1^4$$
$$33^2 = 1^3+4^5+2^6$$
$$271^2 = 1^3+6^5+2^7+4^8$$
$$10014^2 = 2^4+3^5+6^7+10^8+1^9$$
$$44473^2 = 3^2+10^4+12^5+8^6+1^9+7^{11}$$
$$2036295^2 = 4^2+6^3+10^5+9^8+14^{11}+1^{12}+7^{13}$$
$$64711132^2 = 14^1+16^2+5^3+4^6+7^8+9^{12}+10^{13}+11^{15}$$
Can anybody prove/disprove the conjecture that such $\sigma$ will always exist regardless of value of $N$?
(The question was originally asked on MSE)

Empirically, such permutations should exist: if you restrict on permutations for which the exponents are 1, 2,..,$N$, then there are $N!$ sums which do not exceed, say, $2(2N)^N$. The square root of this number is much less than $N!$, so I expect many sums to be perfect squares.
